# Argument to Partial View is the Wrong Type--How is this Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following line in one of my views (cshtml files):

```
@Html.Partial("_ProviderRatingWidget", Model.RatingInfo)
```

In my lab, everything seems to be working fine. But in deployment, we are seeing the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProviderContactInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RatingCategorySummaryModel'.

`Model` is explicitly of type `ProviderContactInfo`, and `Model.RatingInfo` is explicitly of type `RatingCategorySummaryModel`. And so how can this line ever pass type `ProviderContactInfo`?

Can anyone see any possible circumstances where this line could produce that error?

**EDIT**

Oh, I should point out that the line above is also in a partial view. (The partial view is loading another partial view.) That might be related to the problem.

Comment: Could you post the controller that calls the view?

Comment: Can you post the model and the partial view? That would be more helpful than the controller in this situation. What is the data type of RatingInfo on the model? And what is the @model declared as in the partial view? This error is saying they are different.

Comment: @mayabelle: If you read the question, you can see that `RatingInfo` is explicitly of type `RatingCategorySummaryModel`. I think the entire partial view is too much to post. What information do you think would be helpful?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Have you checked if RatingInfo might be null? I believe MVC will automatically pass in the current model (i.e. 
ProviderContactInfo) if it's null.

Comment: @mayabelle: I wondered about it being null. It isn't when I test it in my lab. Do you have any information about what is passed when it's null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have verified that the current model will be passed if the property you are trying to pass is null. You can get around the issue with this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_ProviderRatingWidget", new ViewDataDictionary(Model.RatingInfo));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I was also able to verify that passing `Model.Property` when it is null will pass `Model` instead. That was unexpected. I would've expected the partial view to be able to test for null itself. Good find. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mmm I not test, but maybe this work:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProviderRatingWidget", ((RatingCategorySummaryModel)Model.RatingInfo))
```

Regards.,

k

Comment: No, that is not the problem.